# How can i add custom fields in wordpress in post in twenty seventeen theme

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for solution to find out my problem on how to add custom field in post in twenty seventeen theme in wordpress. Help me solve out this problem in wordpress twenty seventeen theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding custom fields un twenty seventeen can be​ done exactly like with another theme.

You just need to check the Custom field chebox in the Screen options (you can find it at the top right to display them) and everything will appear in post edit screen (mostly at the bottom, under the edit content box).

Some custom fields begining with an underscore are not available on this screen. The only way to find them is to look in the options table with phpmyadmin or browse wp-admin/options.php (only in read-only).
Last solution, create a metabox to list them, [add_meta_boxes references](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes)

Comment: Yes, but how to display that added custome field in home page of theme?

Comment: You can only see those which are available. Every custom field begins with an underscore will not be available